# React-Native: Convert image url to base64 string

Tags: javascript, image, base64, react-native

I'm building a react native app that needs to store images at base64 string format for offline viewing capabilities.

What library / function would give me the best result to store the image as base64 string? assuming my url is "http://www.example.com/image.png".

Also, do I need to make http request to get it before storing it as a string? my logic says yes, but in react native you can load images on the <Image> component without request them first from the server.

What would be the best option to do this in react native?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I use [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), basically it provides lot of file system and network functions make transferring data pretty easy.

> [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) is deprecated

```
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
let imagePath = null;
RNFetchBlob.config({
  fileCache: true
})
  .fetch("GET", "http://www.example.com/image.png")
  // the image is now dowloaded to device's storage
  .then(resp => {
    // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
    imagePath = resp.path();
    return resp.readFile("base64");
  })
  .then(base64Data => {
    // here's base64 encoded image
    console.log(base64Data);
    // remove the file from storage
    return fs.unlink(imagePath);
  });
```

source [Project Wiki](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Fetch-API)

Comment: How to use local image like 'user/Project/example.png'?.

Comment: @Sathya Documentation provides such example with local files Here https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#readfilepath-encodingpromise

Comment: @OliverDixon so it is not good because it does not work for you ?

Comment: Actually, this code will crash the app, causing a FileUriExposedException

Comment: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-fetch-blob (from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`) was resolved to 0.10.6, which depends on

Comment: this package is not maintained now ....

Answer (score 26):

There is a better way:
Install this [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), IF you don't already have it.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

RNFS.readFile(this.state.imagePath, 'base64')
.then(res =>{
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Works on RN `0.63.3`

Comment: When I try to save into a variable, it saves as `[object Object]` instead of the base64 string. How to save the base64 string to a variable?

Comment: It says "At the command line, in your project folder, type: react-native link react-native-fs. Done! No need to worry about manually adding the library to your project."And then down it says Android usage and all that stuff ? Update the documentation plz

Answer (score 15):

The standalone expo FileSystem package makes this simple:

```
const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(photo.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/
- https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-file-system

As 2019-09-27 this package handles both `file://` and `content://` uri's

Comment: above code is only for images not for pdf and other files.

Answer (score 13):

```
 ImageEditor.cropImage(imageUrl, imageSize, (imageURI) => {
      ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(imageURI, (base64Data) => {
          // base64Data contains the base64string of the image
      }, (reason) => console.error(reason));
 }, (reason) => console.error(reason));
```

Comment: React Native warns developers not to use ImageEditor anymore:
Warning: ImageStore is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. To get a base64-encoded string from a local image use either of the following third-party libraries:* expo-file-system: `readAsStringAsync(filepath, 'base64')`* react-native-fs: `readFile(filepath, 'base64')`

Answer (score 9):

To convert image to base64 in React native, the FileReader utility is helpful:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = fileLoadedEvent => {
  const base64Image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(imagepath);
```

This requires [react-native-file](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-file).

Another alternative, and probably the preferred alternative, is to use NativeModules. The [Medium article](https://medium.com/@scottdixon/react-native-creating-a-custom-module-to-upload-camera-roll-images-7a3c26bac309#.e9nh6d8ax) shows how. It requires creating a [native module](https://github.com/scottdixon/react-native-upload-from-camera-roll/blob/master/RCTCustom.m).

```
NativeModules.ReadImageData.readImage(path, (base64Image) => {
  // Do something here.
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64). You have to give image url and it returns the base64 string of image.

```
ImgToBase64.getBase64String('file://youfileurl')
  .then(base64String => doSomethingWith(base64String))
  .catch(err => doSomethingWith(err));
```

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-fetch-blob (from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`) was resolved to 0.10.6, which depends on
      React/Core

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Answer (score 5):

react-native-image-picker includes a base64 data node in the returned object. fyi

Comment: thanks a lot. I just know this about the library I already used. @zematdev

Answer (score 5):

In case you're using expo in a managed workflow and cannot use `react-native-fs`, you can do it using the `expo-file-system` library. Here's a helper function that will do the trick by only providing an image URL and will return a base64 encoded image.
PS: It doesn't contain the base64 prefix, you need to include it yourself based on the image type you have.

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';


async function getImageToBase64(imageURL) {
  let image;

  try {
    const { uri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      imageURL,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'bufferimg.png'
    );

    image = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
      encoding: 'base64',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return image;
}
```

An example usage in a React Native Image component is as follows:

```
<Image
  style={{ width: 48, height: 48 }}
  source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${image}` }}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

**No library need, use built in JS features**

```
export default async function base64File(url) {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await data.blob();
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      resolve(base64data);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I needed to generate a base64 using the url of an image saved in cloudinary and this was super helpful. I didn't need to install any library or whatsoever.

PS: I am on RN Version: 0.70.4 and React Version: 18.1.0

Comment: Same here, React 18.2.0 and RN 0.71.3

Answer (score 2):

> i am using react-native-image-crop-picker
> add includeBase64 prop it will response in  base64 converted image

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  includeBase64:true
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If You are using **react-native-image-picker**
Then it includes base64 string in response object

    if you are  using any  other library i.e. **react-native-document-picker**
    then you have to use **react-native-fs** library 
    
    import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
    
      RNFS.readFile(item.uri, 'base64').then((res) => {
                  //Here in enter code here res you  will get base64 string 
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

// others state
const [base64Image, setBase64Image] = useState(null);
// others code
useEffect(() => {
        async function getBase64() {
          const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUrl, { encoding: 'base64' });      
          const base64Data = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64;
          setBase64Image(base64Data);
        }
        getBase64()
    }, [imageUrl]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another package: `react-native-fs`

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

var data = await RNFS.readFile( "file://path-to-file", 'base64').then(res => { return res });
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For me upalod file mp4 from local file on devies to Facebook or another social:**

```
var data = await RNFS.readFile( `file://${this.data.path}`, 'base64').then(res => { return res });
        const shareOptions = {
            title: 'iVideo',
            message: 'Share video',
            url:'data:video/mp4;base64,'+ data,
            social: Share.Social.FACEBOOK,
            filename: this.data.name , // only for base64 file in Android 
        };     
        Share.open(shareOptions).then(res=>{
           Alert.alert('Share Success`enter code here`!')
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('err share', err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ImgToBase64 from 'react-native-image-base64';
 
ImgToBase64.getBase64String(trainingRooms)
            .then(base64String => {
                console.log("Sourabh____ ImgToBase64 base64String "+base64String );
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Sourabh____ ImgToBase64 error "+err);
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert url image to base64

const getBase64ImageFromUrl = url =>
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(
blob =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
reader.onerror = reject;
blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'image/png'});
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}),
);

await getBase64ImageFromUrl("https://your image url");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).