# Convert Image to base64 in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have used react-native-image-picker and now I select image from the Photo library. To send the that image to API I have to convert it first into base64 and then into byte array. I have the filepath in response.uri. How do I do it?

When I did console.log(response) I am getting this in result

```
'Response = ', {
  fileSize: 6581432,
  longitude: -17.548928333333333,
  uri: 'file:///Users/shubhamb/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B58314DF-F0A9-48D2-B68A-984A02271B72/data/Containers/Data/Application/63143214-8A03-4AC8-A79C-42EC9B82E841/tmp/2AACBC57-0C07-4C98-985E-154668E6A384.jpg',
  fileName: 'IMG_0003.JPG',
  latitude: 65.682895,
  origURL: 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD&ext=JPG',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  height: 2002,
  width: 3000,
  timestamp: '2012-08-08T18:52:11Z',
  isVertical: false,
}
```

Comment: See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908009/react-native-convert-image-url-to-base64-string

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908009/react-native-convert-image-url-to-base64-string

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using **react-native-image-picker**, it already returns the Base64 value in its response

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  const base64Value = response.data;
});
```

[Documentation for the response](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#the-response-object)

Comment: Yeah I did that but when I try to print using alert(base64value) it shows undefined.

Comment: const source = {uri: 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + response.data, isStatic: true} this returns object but then it will work only for jpg.

Comment: Can you tell what am I doing wrong. I also have to convert that base64 into byte array.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get undefined. Can you try console.log(response) and see what the whole value is? As for the byte array, I don't actually have experience on the subject but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray

Comment: Response does not contain data. That is the reason why I am getting undefined.

Comment: That is quite weird, can you check if you set "noData" to true in the options? That might caused the issue

Comment: No I have set "noData" to false in the options.

Answer (score 5):

I suddenly ran into this issue while updating my app. What I found is that previous `react-native-image-picker` used to provide **base64** as **response.data**. But now there is an **includeBase64** in the **options** object so that you can control whether you need the base64 data or not. So my code became something like the following

```
captureTradeLicenseImage() {
    let options = {
        maxHeight: 250,
        maxWidth: 350,
        includeBase64: true //add this in the option to include base64 value in the response
    }
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response)  => {
        console.log('Response = ', response)
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker')
        }
        else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error)
        }
        else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton)
        }
        else if (response.fileSize > 5242880) {
            Alert.alert(
                "Nilamhut Say\'s",
                "Oops! the photos are too big. Max photo size is 4MB per photo. Please reduce the resolution or file size and retry",
                [
                    { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log('ok Pressed') }
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
            )
        }
        else {
            this.setState({tradeLicenseImageData: response.base64}) //access like this
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standalone expo FileSystem package makes this simple:

```
const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(photo.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/
- https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-file-system

As 2019-09-27 this package handles both `file://` and `content://` uri's

Answer (score 2):

I'm too late but if I can help others that is looking how to get the **base64** data from an image:
In the **options** object you have to set the base64 option to **true**, like this:

```
const options = {
   title: 'Choose an Image',
   base64: true
};

ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as that:

```
import { CameraOptions, ImagePickerResponse, launchCamera } from 'react-native-image-picker';

Wrap in your component: 

const [b64, setB64] = useState<string>("");

const manageImage = async (response: ImagePickerResponse) => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
      return;
    } else if (response.assets) {
        if (response.assets?.length > 0) {
          setB64(response.assets[0].base64 ? response.assets[0].base64 : "");
        }
    }
  }

launchCamera(options, (response) => {
  manageImage(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

including

```
includeBase64: true
```

in the options did return the base64 string for me.