# How to change local image to base64 in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I try to use `FileReader` get the error:
`Error: Unable to resolve data for blob`

```
import Room1 from 'assets/image/livingRoom.jpg'; // my local jpg


const encodeImageFileAsURL = (element) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(element);
  console.log('reader', reader);
};

encodeImageFileAsURL(Room1);
```

How to change local image to base64 ? Thanks.

Comment: you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908009/react-native-convert-image-url-to-base64-string

Comment: Thanks, I will try it to check if data comes from my local works or not.