# How to get image as base 64 from url react native

Tags: react-native, base64

I am trying to fetch an image with the following code:

```
await fetch(
        `${BACKEND_URL}/api/visitors/getAvatar/${visitor.visitor.accountId}`
      )
```

I am getting a response in this format :

```
{
   "_bodyBlob":{
      "_data":{
         "__collector":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "blobId":"7d70537a-3869-40d6-a9d1-bf092c2d7151",
         "offset":0,
         "size":10188
      }
   },
   "_bodyInit":{
      "_data":{
         "__collector":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "blobId":"7d70537a-3869-40d6-a9d1-bf092c2d7151",
         "offset":0,
         "size":10188
      }
   },
   "bodyUsed":false,
   "headers":{
      "map":{
         "access-control-allow-credentials":"true",
         "access-control-allow-origin":"*",
         "alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-28=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-27=\":443\"; ma=86400",
         "cache-control":"public, max-age=86400",
         "cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC",
         "cf-ray":"6b432d06cb116b3f-AMS",
         "content-length":"10188",
         "content-type":"image/png",
         "date":"Fri, 26 Nov 2021 12:38:48 GMT",
         "etag":"W/\"27cc-PGkLO2FScsiEoWiW9u+CmIhDkaQ\"",
         "expect-ct":"max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
         "nel":"{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}",
         "report-to":"{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=tFCAld4YJbsHJotK05x0jrG%2FUB2tWO%2BOjAd0LTRyhuwuSJzpu5OkPtUo1CGavatZPQb62WYJL2J%2BGcD%2BI4R2GS0HItiwIBtpOPBqB70yyPCx6AU6N5BCuCtM5Ck4WgSN2cf0yWpKV6TIRxzwvqIz\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}",
         "server":"cloudflare",
         "x-content-type-options":"nosniff",
         "x-download-options":"noopen",
         "x-frame-options":"DENY",
         "x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block"
      }
   }
```

How to extract an image as base64 from this? I have tried a couple of packages like `react-native-fs` and `rn-fetch-blob` but they are not maintained or deprecated!

Comment: Is `https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=tFCAld4YJbsHJotK05x0jrG%2FUB2tWO%2BOjAd0LTRyhuwuSJzpu5OkPtUo1CGavatZPQb62WYJL2J%2BGcD%2BI4R2GS0HItiwIBtpOPBqB70yyPCx6AU6N5BCuCtM5Ck4WgSN2cf0yWpKV6TIRxzwvqIz` your image URL?

Comment: i can't say anything here i am stuck here ... @Rohit ... how to parse this into url and see whether this is the url ! i have tried to load it but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Native: Convert image url to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908009/react-native-convert-image-url-to-base64-string)

Comment: @AndreyProgr no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

After using couple of packages, I got this trick to get base64. After you have uploaded any image, you can use **rn-fetch-blob** to convert the url to base64.

```
RNFetchBlob.fs
      .readFile(
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? url : url.replace('file://', ''),
        'base64',
      ).then(res => {
         console.log(res, "base64 result");
     })
```

One point to note here is that when you upload file in iOS, you might get url in the format "**file://**", if thats the case then remove that from url and then pass it just like I have mentioned in the above code.

Comment: it is unmaintained @Akshay

Comment: I have not faced any issue till now for reading, how much I have worked on RnFetchBlob, they have some issues when it comes to writing(Write Permissions). I have worked on multiple apps where we have used RnFetchBlob and we didn't notice any serious concern as of now. Also similar functionality can be seen in react-native-fs if that is better.

Comment: and one more thing ... i am not reading from local storage but from api ...

Comment: Any particular reason why you are looking to convert it into base64, when you get it from api?

Comment: want to use it with ViewShot for a sticker

Comment: Is it then possible for the backend to convert it onto base64 and send it to you, because in react-native, I did some research and found out that these 2 were the only running packages that does the job, other packages are either too new, not much downloads, or have some issues.